# runas with /savecred not working from windows service

Tags: passwords, windows-services, runas

I have a Windows service (our integration build software) that tries to run a batch file using runas /savecred.

I ran the command from the command-line and provided the password. When I execute it afterwards, it doesn't ask me for the password. But when I run it from the Windows service, it keeps asking for the password.

I've tried running the service under various user credentials, including the same credentials I I used when I initially supplied the password to runas as well as the actual account I'm trying use in the runas call.

But no matter what I do, it insists on asking for the password.

Does anyone know how I can use runas with /savecred from a Windows Service?

Comment: Oh, and just to avoid wasting time, I'm aware that runas is insecure. It's nto a problem for my needs.

Comment: I would include the code of how you are executing the batch file and re-ask this question on Stack Overflow. This is a programming problem, not a end user problem. (be sure to delete this original question on Super User or have it moved to Stack Overflow by a moderator)

Comment: Why not just run the service with the credentials of the user that can access the resource you're trying to run?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain My question is in regards to using `runas` from a Windows service. I'm using it to run tools used by a software development team, but I'm not clear on how this is a "programming problem."

Comment: @techie007 because this windows service will eventually (I hope) be running 6 different batch files, each under a different account.

Comment: How are you using "runas" from a Service if you didn't create a custom service?

Comment: @techie007 It's a continuous integration server. It uses a config file and executes a number of applications. It launches compilers, dos commands, runs unit tests, etc. I'm simply having it run : `runas /user:domain\userid /savecred runtests.bat`